# Windows reset homegroup

Tags: windows-10, homegroup

I do have a homegroup originating from one older PC. This PC is gone, so I can also not access the homegroup password anymore.

If I try to create a new homegroup this is not possible. I get the option to join the homegroup (from the old PC, unknown password), no option to leave that group or a create a new one.

How can I reset the homegroup settings and start a new homegroup for my network on a new PC?

Comment: try deleting the contents of your peer networking folder. `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\PeerNetworking`, then restart and try again

Comment: I have tried that one on my new computer and restarted it, but still no option to create a new homegroup

Comment: Do you have more than one PC in the network? If so I'd recommend shutting them all down, bring one back up, and see if you can create a new homegroup from that one. Homegroup PCs report to each other, so another PC might be telling everyone else the old Homegroup still exists. All online computers must be removed from the homegroup before a new one is created, per M$'s recommendations.

Comment: that's it, thanks. I have deleted from `PeerNetworking` as recommended, then shut down everything. Afterwards I can create an new Homegroup  on my new PC. You can post your comment as answer and I will accept it.